# How to calculate score after filter in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick, elasticsearch-6.5

I want the score to be calculated after the filter is applied.
Right now, the score gets calculated considering all the documents in the index. And other entity documents interfere with the score calculation which I don't want.
eg: I have multiple stores, and each store items should be independently scored.

I tried the score_function, but could not make it work.
Indexing items in-store separately can solve the problem, but the store can be in thousands.

Each store can have thousands--200000 documents.
Stores can be up to. 10000. can be more, customer can create as many as they want.

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [{
      "match": {
        "normalized_tokens": {
          "query": "Where can i find the chocolate",
          "analyzer": "custom_analyzed_document_search",
          "operator": "or"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "match": {
        "normalized_tokens": {
          "query": "find chocolate",
          "analyzer": "custom_analyzed_document_search",
          "operator": "or"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "term": {
        "document": "Where can i find the chocolate"
      }
    }],
    "filter": [{
      "bool": {
        "should": [{
          "terms": {
            "department_id": []
          }
        }, {
          "terms": {
            "store_id": [1,2,3]
          }
        }]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your query, sample docs and index mapping also what made you think that score is not applied after filtering the docs

Comment: Sure, let me give the query. 
I checked the score, by removing the filter and adding a filter back the score was the same, and I read it filters just filter out the record and do not affect the score.

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja added the example query .

Comment: yeah looking at the query, and yes, you are correct as filters are just removing the other stores but after that BM25 similarity algo of ES which calculates the score has IDF(inverse document frequency) due to which all documents in your index(irrespective) of stores will contribute to IDF hence score is not totally unique to a store

Comment: I would suggest you have a loon at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html which gives you several option to control the score process

Comment: if nothing works you can still use the scripted similarity https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#scripted_similarity but you need to tweak it according to your use-case

Comment: Let me try these. thank you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224506/discussion-between-elasticsearch-ninja-and-jbmyid).